# How to compute basis of nullspace with Eigen library?

Tags: c++, linear-algebra, eigen

How to compute **basis of nullspace** of a matrix with Eigen library?

I tried to find **explicit function name** to compute null basis and also, as a workaround, to find method for **computing rref of a matrix**(as we're able to get null basis from rref).

But I couldn't find any relevant functions names.

I think there's must be solution for this, but I know not much about Eigen library and Eigen's code also very difficult to me to understand.

Please suggest me the solution for this problem.

Comment: @OldProgrammer Are you pointing that this is not coding problem? Sorry, I don't understand what you want to point.

Comment: Are you sure you need the rref? What is your actual problem? Linear least squares?

Comment: @kchoose2 I want to compute basis of null space. Not just projecting to the null space.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can get a basis of the null space using [Eigen::FullPivLU::kernel()](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/classEigen_1_1FullPivLU.html#a6e8f1d2fcbd86d3dc5a8a013b6e7200a) method:

```
FullPivLU<MatrixXd> lu(A);
MatrixXd A_null_space = lu.kernel();
```

Answer (score 5):

FullPivLU is most expensive computationally in Eigen, http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/group__DenseDecompositionBenchmark.html.

A quicker alternative is to use CompleteOrthogonalDecomposition. This code uses four fundamental subspaces of a matrix (google four fundamental subspaces and URV decomposition):

```
Matrix<double, Dynamic, Dynamic> mat37(3,7);
mat37 = MatrixXd::Random(3, 7);

CompleteOrthogonalDecomposition<Matrix<double, Dynamic, Dynamic> > cod;
cod.compute(mat37);
cout << "rank : " << cod.rank() << "\n";
// Find URV^T
MatrixXd V = cod.matrixZ().transpose();
MatrixXd Null_space = V.block(0, cod.rank(),V.rows(), V.cols() - cod.rank());
MatrixXd P = cod.colsPermutation();
Null_space = P * Null_space; // Unpermute the columns
// The Null space:
std::cout << "The null space: \n" << Null_space << "\n" ;
// Check that it is the null-space:
std::cout << "mat37 * Null_space = \n" << mat37 * Null_space  << '\n';
```

Comment: Thank you for this answer (+1). Do you know whether we can get the image (column-space) of the matrix with this decomposition?

Comment: Extract the Q matrix using MatrixXd = cod.matrixQ(); and the first r columns, where r is the rank (you can extract it using cod.rank() ) is the column space of the matrix.

Comment: Yes, I've found the way in the meantime: <https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/q/36308/14840>. Sorry, I should have notified you.

Comment: This does not work for complex numbers (e.g. std::complex<float>), while the accepted answer does. Could anyone propose an edit for complex matrices?

Comment: It seems to work for complex numbers if we use conjugate at the line ```MatrixXd V = cod.matrixZ().transpose();``` -> ```MatrixXd V = cod.matrixZ().transpose().conjugate();```. Not sure, could we get some confirmation on this?

Comment: Yes should work fine for complex type if you use cod.matrixZ().transpose().conjugate() or in short cod.matrixZ().adjoint()

Answer (score 1):

Alternative: Use OpenCV to calculate null space:

```
`
cv::Mat EpipolarConstraint::getNullSpace(cv::Mat p)
{
    cv::SVD svd = cv::SVD(p, cv::SVD::FULL_UV);
    cv::Mat vt_ = svd.vt;
    int i;
    for (i = 1; i <= 3; i++)
    {
        if (p.at<double>(i - 1, i - 1) == 0)
        {
            break;
        }
    }
    cv::Mat result = vt_(cv::Rect(0, i-1, p.cols, vt_.rows-i+1));
    cv::Mat result_t;
    cv::transpose(result, result_t);
    return result_t;
}`
```