# Using Eigen - how to solve sparse (SPD) linear systems with zero columns?

Tags: c++, sparse-matrix, linear-algebra, eigen, algebra

(I'm using Eigen C++ library)

I need to solve a system of equations with the form of `Ax = 0` in order to find the `x` vector (A is sparse).

**EDIT:** A is SPD (symmetric positive definite)

Because some of the `x` values are known, I removed them out of A to create `Af` and into another matrix `Ac` with the same dimensions as `A`, and multiplied `-Ac` with a vector that has the known `x` values and zeros in all other places to create a vector `b`.

Now I try to solve `Af * x = b` using `SparseLU<SparseMatrix<float>>`, but it fails because the factorization doesn't work. I get this error:

> THE MATRIX IS STRUCTURALLY SINGULAR ... ZERO COLUMN AT 480

Why is it a problem that I have a zero column? A zero row would have been a problem for sure but a zero column? I just changed something like this:

`x_1 + x_2 = 0`

`x_2 = 3`

to

`x_1 + 0 = -3`

The solution is `x_1 = -3 & x_2 = 3` even though I would have had a zero column had I put the equations in a matrix.

How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have "A" and "b = 0" given, and know A is symmetric positive definite.
Because A is spd, it has no nontrivial null-space (this is an important property). That is, the only "x" that exists such that Ax = b = 0 is x = 0.

So you won't find a solution if given nonzero values. It will always be x = 0.
I say this to emphasize Eigen can't solve the problem, by the way it's formulated.

Comment: This makes so much sense. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

> Why is it a problem that I have a zero column?

Because it means that your equation ignores one of the components of the vector of unknowns, which results in the solution being non-unique (any value of the ignored unknown could satisfy the equation).

> Because some of the `x` values are known, I removed them out of A to create `Af` and into another matrix `Ac` with the same dimensions as `A`, and multiplied `-Ac` with a vector that has the known `x` values and zeros in all other places to create a vector `b`.

I'm not sure how exactly you removed the `x` values from the matrix. They aren't the components of the matrix, so they can't be removed. But if they are indeed known, you should *substitute* them into the system of equations, and then remove corresponding columns from the matrix, and then remove extraneous rows to make the matrix square.

E.g. suppose you have `A` and `b` defined as follows:

```
    ⎛1 2 3⎞
A = ⎜2 4 5⎟,
    ⎝3 5 6⎠
b = (3,-5,8)ᵀ,
```

and your equation is

```
Ax=b.
```

Let `x₂` be known to be -32. We can substitute it, yielding the following equation:

```
A'x'+c=b,
```

where

```
     ⎛1 3⎞
A' = ⎜2 5⎟,
     ⎝3 6⎠
x' = (x₁,x₃)ᵀ,
c = (-64,-128,-160)ᵀ.
```

`c` here is the product of the second column of `A` with `x₂`. After moving `c` to the RHS to yield `k=b-c` there, you'll get an overdetermined (albeit consistent) system

```
A'x'=k,
```

so you should remove one of the rows from `A` and the same row from `k`. E.g. removing the last row will result in the equation

```
A"x'=k',
```

where

```
     ⎛1 3⎞
A" = ⎝2 5⎠,
k' = (67,123)ᵀ,
```

and whose solution is `x'=(x₁,x₃)ᵀ=(34,11)ᵀ`. This equation can be solved using the usual linear solvers that work with square matrices.

Answer (score 0):

My linear algebra is a bit rusty.

In order for a matrix to have an unique solution, the rank of the matrix needs to be the same as the dimension. If you have a zero column then rank will be one less then the dimension and you have one free variable.

If you are trying to solve `Ax = 0` then it is the `null space` that you are after, try looking at this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34662940/how-to-compute-basis-of-nullspace-with-eigen-library).

Comment: OK I understand why the columns can't be zero, but my problem is more specific than simply `Ax = 0`. I need to find `Ax = 0` when A is symmetric positive definite and I know some of the `x` values